# What is Warning: Replacing memory \MEM with list of registers?

Tags: verilog, yosys

I have this little code that displays a binary count on LEDs:

```
module main (
    input clk,
    output [7:0] LED
    );

    reg [7:0] MEM [0:'hffff];
    reg [7:0] tx_byte;

    reg [31:0] cta = 0;
    assign LED = ~cta[31:24];

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    cta = cta + 1;
    tx_byte = MEM['hfe06];
    MEM['hfe04] = 0; // Warning: Replacing memory \MEM with list of registers. S
  end
  
endmodule
```

It compile with no errors/no warning if I comment out line 15

```
  //  MEM['hfe04] = 0;
```

but uncommented it and I get

```
[Tue Aug 23 07:20:40 2022] Processing iCESugar_1_5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yosys -p "synth_ice40 -json hardware.json" -q main.v
Warning: Replacing memory \MEM with list of registers. See main.v:15
========================= [SUCCESS] Took 1.52 seconds =========================
```

Code still works, however.

Can some explains what this warning means? I've having issues compiling a larger project (compiler hangs my PC) and this warning seems related.

Hardware: ICESugar 1.5
Toolkit: Apio 0.8.1

Comment: `MEM` is not doing anything. You're setting one byte to zero, but never reading its value, and you are reading another byte that you are never setting the value of. So the synthesis tool is optimising the memory away, replacing it with registers instead.

Comment: In the real app, MEM is loaded with `$readmemh` and updated by another module, but the warning is the same, **and the compiler hang up**.

Comment: Consider the possibility that you are using MEM in a way that cannot be synthesised to  a memory block (for example, clearing all of it on RESET, or accessing more than 2 locations in a clock cycle, or not registering the address or output). Compare your usage with the synth style guide and work on following that more closely.

Comment: @user_1818839. Can't access 2 locations in a clock cycle? Didn't know that. Can elaborate or point to docs?

Comment: Read the comment more carefully, then read the BlockRam docs re: dual port memories.